# Decomposition of triangular matrix as Toeplitz matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, toeplitz-matrices

How can I decompose a triangular matrix into a product of Toeplitz matrices or circular/Henkel matrices?

Comment: Hi. Can you show definitions or a bit of your work on this so far? This way it is easier to help you!

Comment: I want to parameterize a matrix in minimum possible values. So the best representation is Toeplitz/circulant/Henkal matrix as we can generate the whole matrix from just one row. So i need ways we can do this transformation may be via decomposition, transformation or ant other operation.

Comment: https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/work/toeplitz.pdf